# Checking if a string is a number in discord.py

Tags: python, string, numeric

Say for example I have a command that requires 2 arguments, I have an if statement already that checks to see if all arguments are present, however, in this scenario; the first argument should be a number. This is roughly what the code is:

```py
@bot.command()
async def rand(ctx,*args):
    if len(args) < 2:
        await ctx.send("you are missing arguments")
    elif isinstance(args[0], int) == False:
        await ctx.send("You have not provided an integer")
```

However the `isinstance(args[0], int) == False:` is always triggered, I'm guessing this is because the argument is initially taken as a string. Instead of checking the variable type, is it possible to check if the variable is souly a number?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the string represents a numeric value, try:

```
if not args[0].isnumeric():
    await ctx.send("You have not provided an integer")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
args[0].isnumeric()
```

I think you could try this function.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure it's a string use isdigit()

```
elif args[0].isdigit() is False:
```

or you can check both objects and string:

```
elif (args[0].isdigit() == False) and (isinstance(args[0], int) == False):
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're declaring arguments in a question, I wouldn't put them into a list unless you have no idea how many given arguments a user is going to put in. This module is built to take a command like `!command arg1 arg2` and parse those to be used as individual arguments, so I would advise using the intended argument feature. Within that feature, you are also able to declare types that you need your arguments to be in.

In this example, the `@rand.error` decorator will intercept any errors coming from the command and process them there. This allows us to have a much cleaner code that is much easier to read and understand.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def rand(ctx, arg1: int, arg2):
    await ctx.send(f"{arg1}, {arg2}")

@rand.error
async def rand_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("You have not provided two arguments")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.errors.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("You have provided a bad argument")
```